# Opencl - Transfer Global memory Work-Group + border to Local memory

Tags: c++, memory, opencl

Here a draft of code I produced :

```
void __kernel myKernel(__global const short* input,
                       __global short* output,
                       const int width,
                       const int height){                         


    // Always square. (and 16x16 in our example)
    const uint local_size = get_local_size(0);

    // Get the work-item col/row index
    const uint wi_c = get_local_id(0);
    const uint wi_r = get_local_id(1);

    // Get the global col/row index
    const uint g_c = get_global_id(0);
    const uint g_r = get_global_id(1);

    // Declare a local array NxN 
    const uint arr_size = local_size *local_size ;
    __local short local_in[arr_size]; 

    // Transfer the global memory for into a local one.
    local_in[wi_c  + wi_r*local_size ] = input[g_c + g_r*width];

    // Wait that all the work-item are sync
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // Now add code to process on the local array (local_in).
```

As far as I understand OpenCL work-group/work-item, this is what I need to do to copy a global 16x16 ROI of from global to local memory. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, since I'm beginning at this).

So after the barrier, each element in local_in can be access via `wi_c + wi_r*local_size`.

But now let's do something tricky. If I want for each work-item in my work group to work on a 3x3 neighborhood, I will need a 18x18 local_in array.

But how to create this ? Since I have only 16x16=256 work-item (threads), but I need 18x18=324 (missing 68 threads to do it).

My basic idea should be to do:

```
if(wi_c == 0 && wi_r == 0){
    // Code that copy the border into the new array that should be
    // local_in[(local_size+2)*(local_size+2)];         
}
```

But this is terrible, since the first work-item (1st thread) will have to handle all the border and the rest of the work-items in this group will just be waiting this 1st work-item to finish. (Again, this is my understanding of OpenCL, might be wrong).

So here are my real question:

1. Is there another easier solution for this kind of problem ? Like changing the NDRange Local size to be overlapping or something ?
2. I start to read about coalesced memory access, is my first draft of code look like it ? I don't think so, since I'm using a "stride" approach to load the global memory. But I don't understand how I could change the first part of that code to be efficient also.
3. Once the barrier is reached, the processing continue of each work-item to get a final value that need to be stored back into the global output array. Should I put again a barrier before this "write" or all good to leave all the work-item finish their self ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different approaches and I came with the final version, which is less "if" and use thread as much as possible (On second phase, might not be fully efficient since few thread are idle, but it's the best I was able to get).

The principle is to set an origin (start pos) at the top-left corner and create Read/Write index from this position using loop index. The loop start at the local id position in 2D. So all 256 work-items write their first element, and on phase two only 68 work-items on 256 will complete the 2 bottom rows + 2 right columns.

I'm not a OpenCL pro yet, so this could still have more improvement (maybe loop unroll, I don't know).

```
    __local float wrkSrc[324];
    const int lpitch = 18;

    // Add halfROI to handle the corner
    const int lcol = get_local_id(0);
    const int lrow = get_local_id(1);

    const int2 gid = { col, row };
    const int2 lid = { lcol, lrow };

    // Always get the most Top-left corner of that ROI to extract.
    const int2 startPos = gid - lid - halfROI;

    // Loop on each thread to get their right ID.
    // Thread with id < 2 * halfROI will process more then others, but not that much an issue.
    for ( int x = lid.x; x < lpitch; x += 16 ) {
        for ( int y = lid.y; y < lpitch; y += 16 ) {

            // Get the position to write into the local array.
            const int lidx = x + y * lpitch;

            // Get the position to read into the global memory (src)
            const int2 readPos = startPos + (int2)( x, y );

            // Is inside ?
            if ( readPos.x >= 0 && readPos.x < width && readPos.y >= 0 && readPos.y < height )
                wrkSrc[lidx] = src[readPos.x + readPos.y * lab_new_pitch];
            else
                wrkSrc[lidx] = 0.0f;
        }
    }
```